# Updating package.json version with Unleash does not actually update the package.json

Tags: javascript, git, package.json, git-tag

We are using Netflix unleash to automatically update the version in our package.json file and update a CHANGELOG.md file. For everyone else on my team, when they run the unleash command they see their package.json automatically update the version and then get automatically committed and pushed to the branch. That is the expected outcome. However, for me the package.json does not update or show as changed in the git log. The CHANGELOG is updated and committed/pushed. If I wait a few minutes and open package.json in a different IDE or text editor it shows the new tagged version suddenly, yet git log or git status does not show that it was changed in any way.

I have tried several times to delete the repo and clone again. I have deleted node_modules and reinstalled unleash. I have commented out any aliases and bash_profile to rule out those interfering with any commands in the unleash program. I have upgraded to the latest version of git, and LTS of node. I am running this on a Mac 10.13.6 High Sierra

`$ unleash --no-publish --minor`

```
[13:53:25] === UNLEASH ===
[13:53:25] Utilizing next version for changelog:  2.19.0
[13:53:25] Using repo type:  github
[13:53:25] Generating changelog from v2.18.0 to HEAD...
[13:53:25] Parsed 1 commits.
[13:53:25]
[13:53:30] [DS-24401-scroll-bugfix f450557] docs(CHANGELOG): Update changelog
 1 file changed, 9 insertions(+)
 husky > pre-commit (node v10.14.0)
No staged files match any of provided globs.
husky > commit-msg (node v10.14.0)

[13:53:30] Utilizing bumpType minor
[13:53:30] Retrieving latest git commit...
[13:53:30] Getting next version of type:  minor
[13:53:30] Incrementing from version:  2.18.0
[13:53:30] Bumped 'package.json' version to: 2.19.0
[13:53:32] On branch DS-24401-scroll-bugfix
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/DS-24401-scroll-bugfix' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
 husky > pre-commit (node v10.14.0)
No staged files match any of provided globs.

[13:53:32] Tagging as: v2.19.0
[13:53:32]
[13:53:35]  To https://git.forge.lmig.com/scm/direct-sales/barker.git
   af1eca5..f450557  DS-24401-scroll-bugfix -> DS-24401-scroll-bugfix
 * [new tag]         v2.19.0 -> v2.19.0

✨  Done in 11.62s.
```

I expect to see 2 files updated, the CHANGELOG and the package.json.
The package.json is not being updated and included with the unleash commit and push operation.